# Get input tag with condition

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to get input tag if a text is Mr. A text can be Mr or Mrs

```
    <label for="id_gender1" class="top">
        <div class="radio" id="uniform-id_gender1">
            <span class="checked">
                <input type="radio" name="id_gender" id="id_gender1" value="1">
                </span>
            </div>
                        Mr.
                        
        
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
//label[contains(.,'Mr.')]//input
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work and I used //label[contains(child::text()[2],'Mr.')]//input and it works but I don't want to use index (2) b/c it is not a best practice.

Comment: But I see the text belongs to `label` node itself. Strange. Also, have you tried `//label[contains(.,'Mr.')]//input` ?

Comment: It worked but you can explain why we need to use . at here?

Comment: `.` stands for `any` attribute i.e. node with tag name "label" with some (any) attribute that contains "Mr." value.

Comment: As about why `text()` didn't work for you while `.` worked - it depends on what tools / technology you are working with, does it use 1.0 Xpath or 2.0 and higher protocol.